# Horizontal data into Vertical

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import-from-excel

I have horizontal table (Table1) and I need it to transform it into (Table2)

**Table1:**

```
CEO     SALESMAN    PRODUCT(1)  PRODUCT(2)  PRODUCT(3)  PRODUCT(4)  PRODUCT(5)  ... PRODUCT(N)
------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------      ----------
MIKE    ANDERSON    76787,00    19388,00    0,00        2723,00     217,00          6581,00
JOHN    ANGELA      0,00        0,00        73088,00    0,00        0,00            0,00
JACK    JEFF        24716,00    0,00        2995,00     0,00        0,00            0,00
STUART  MICHAEL     0,00        23338,00    42656,00    0,00        0,00            0,00
```

**Table2:**

```
CEO     SALESMAN    PRODUCTS    VALUE
------- ----------- ----------  --------
MIKE    ANDERSON    PRODUCT(1)  76787,00
JOHN    ANGELA      PRODUCT(1)  0,00
JACK    JEFF        PRODUCT(1)  24716,00
STUART  MICHAEL     PRODUCT(1)  0,00
MIKE    ANDERSON    PRODUCT(2)  19388,00
JOHN    ANGELA      PRODUCT(2)  0,00
JACK    JEFF        PRODUCT(2)  0,00
STUART  MICHAEL     PRODUCT(2)  23338,00
MIKE    ANDERSON    PRODUCT(3)  0,00
JOHN    ANGELA      PRODUCT(3)  73088,00
JACK    JEFF        PRODUCT(3)  2995,00
STUART  MICHAEL     PRODUCT(3)  42656,00
MIKE    ANDERSON    PRODUCT(4)  2723,00
JOHN    ANGELA      PRODUCT(4)  0,00
JACK    JEFF        PRODUCT(4)  0,00
STUART  MICHAEL     PRODUCT(4)  0,00
MIKE    ANDERSON    PRODUCT(5)  217,00
JOHN    ANGELA      PRODUCT(5)  0,00
JACK    JEFF        PRODUCT(5)  0,00
STUART  MICHAEL     PRODUCT(5)  0,00
MIKE    ANDERSON    ...     ...
JOHN    ANGELA      ...     ...
JACK    JEFF        ...     ...
STUART  MICHAEL     ...     ...
MIKE    ANDERSON    PRODUCT(N)  6581,00
JOHN    ANGELA      PRODUCT(N)  0,00
JACK    JEFF        PRODUCT(N)  0,00
STUART  MICHAEL     PRODUCT(N)  0,00
```

What I've tried so far is to BULK INSERT Table1 into a temporary table and then work with this data until I get what I want. The problem is the N in PRODUCT() columns is variable so I can't create a temporary table with fixed columns and I need a dynamic query that somehow can read the quantity of products columns and work with it.

**BULK INSERT**

```
BULK INSERT #temp
FROM '\\path\file.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 1,
FIELDTERMINATOR= ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
CODEPAGE='RAW'
);
```

**Temporary table:**

```
CREATE TABLE    #temp(
col1    varchar(100)    null,
col2    varchar(100)    null,
col3    varchar(100)    null,
col4    varchar(100)    null,
col5    varchar(100)    null,
...
col397  varchar(100)    null,
col398  varchar(100)    null,
col399  varchar(100)    null,
col400  varchar(100)    null
)
```

When I run the BULK INSERT I get this error:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

This happens because I created a temporary table with fixed 400 columns and there were 127 product columns.

I'm trying to avoid things like these:

```
DECLARE @NUM_ROWS INT

SET     @NUM_ROWS = 123

IF @NUM_ROWS = 1
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE    #temp(
col1    varchar(100)    null
)
END

IF @NUM_ROWS = 2
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE    #temp(
col1    varchar(100)    null,
col2    varchar(100)    null,
)
END

...

IF @NUM_ROWS = 400
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE    #temp(
col1    varchar(100)    null,
col2    varchar(100)    null,
...
col4    varchar(100)    null,
)
END

BULK INSERT #temp
FROM '\\path\file.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 1,
FIELDTERMINATOR= ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
CODEPAGE='RAW'
);
```

**@NUM_ROWS** would be the number of columns I would create the temp table.

Does anyone know a way I can import this .csv file into SQL Server dynamically? By dynamically I mean creating a temporary table with the number of columns of PRODUCTS I'm bulk inserting. Or a workaround to avoid that error I posted above.

Comment: Can you do any manual manipulation of the csv file prior to loading it? Or does this process need to be 100% automated?

Comment: Sure, I could manipulate the .csv file before. Actually, It would be better to manipulate it before. I've search about manipulating it and I found out about transposing when pasting values, but it didn't help.

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or do you need to repeat it?

Comment: @podiluska I need to repeat it. I'll receive about 16 .csv files like this every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat manual approach:

1. Open the .csv file with Excel
2. Add 400 column names to the first row.  They don't have to be the *actual* names of the fields of course. Just placeholders.  This way, the file will have 400 columns when you resave it. (I call this the manual approach, but you can automate this with a VBA script)

From here on, it's all SQL:

1. Using a standard bulk insert, import this into a staging table with 400 columns.
2. Insert your data into table2 using something like:

> ```
> Insert into Table2
> Select CEO, Salesmen, 1 as ProductNum, [Product(1)] from Table1 where [Product(1)] is not null
> union
> Select CEO, Salesmen, 2 as ProductNum, [Product(2)] from Table1 where [Product(2)] is not null
> ...
> union
> Select CEO, Salesmen, 400 as ProductNum, [Product(400)] from Table1 where [Product(400)] is not null
> ```

Sure, 400 lines of this would be ugly, but you can easily read it and count from 1 to 400.

Comment: That's a simple great idea, that way I could use a fixed 400 columns temporary table and would work to any file. All I have to do later is delete the `TOP 1` from the temporary table.

Comment: Since the Products names won't be the same everytime, I will have to do the SQL part other way. The products columns won't be longer than 200 columns so I will reserve 200 columns to put the product description and do something like this: First I insert a column with IDs then UPDATE #temp SET column204 = select column4 where ID = 2, UPDATE #temp SET column205 = select column5 where ID = 2, UPDATE #temp SET column206 = select column6 where ID = 2... and so on, this way I will know column4 is related to column205, 5 to 205, 6 to 206, etc. And final I will do what you suggested.

Comment: `Insert into Table2
Select CEO, Salesmen, column4 as product_value, column204 as product_description from #temp
union
Select CEO, Salesmen, column5, column205 from #temp
...
union
Select CEO, Salesmen, column200, column400 from #temp`

Comment: Regarding your first comment, bulk insert has an optional argument called FirstRow you can set to 2.  No need to delete the top 1 from the temp table.

Comment: I like your idea.  It sounds like you're trying to abstract out the product names from the column names by storing them in their own columns.  Good luck.

Comment: It works! Thanks, I forgot about `FirstRow` and I added it to the code. Since your answer was the first step to conclude this code, I'm marking it as answer. Thanks for your time too @podiluska.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the CSV into Excel, then save it as a CSV again, then it will format it to have a fixed number of columns.

You can create your temporary table with a loop and dynamic SQL

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @numcols int = 8

select @sql = ''
declare @i int = 1

select @sql = @sql + ', c' + convert(varchar(5), number) + ' varchar(10) ' 
from master..spt_values 
where type='p' and number between 1 and @numcols

select @sql = 'create table ##temp (' + substring(@sql, 3, len(@sql)) + ')'
select @sql

exec sp_executeSQl @sql

BULK INSERT ##temp  
FROM '\\path\file.csv'  
WITH  
(  
FIRSTROW = 1,  
FIELDTERMINATOR= ';',  
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
CODEPAGE='RAW'  
);
```

From there you just apply an [Unpivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to convert the table from columns to rows.

Comment: When running the code above I get the following error: 
`(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 82, Line 15
Invalid object name '#temp'.` And about using Unpivot, I would have to `SELECT` a static list of columns of PRODUCTS which wouldn't help since the products may vary.

Comment: MY fault. There should be two ## before the temp.. If your products vary, then you will need to build the unpivot via dynamic sql.